# Getting status of daemon-socket: Operation not permitted while invoking nix-shell (MacOs)

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, plutus-playground, nix-shell, macos

### Plutus Pioneers Week 01 exercise.

- cloned the plutus-app directory
- edited the nix.conf file (added the iohk binaries reference)
- moved to the plutus-app directory

After downloading, linking and compilation ends, I get the following error  when invoking the nix-shell.

`error: getting status of /nix/var/nix/daemon-socket/socket: Operation not permitted`

Tried:

- Rebooting (in case it was a daemon problem)
- `sudo` in case of permissions problems.

Console output and error.

```
Setting gitrev of /nix/store/4hwiz5g25mnrjb3a6qjdcvl4fpvkm4fq-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0/bin/cardano-cli ... OK
"Bundling /nix/store/vv3k4s0gzkvdbirq5iiah15w920z6aql-zlib-1.2.11/lib/libz.dylib in /nix/store/4hwiz5g25mnrjb3a6qjdcvl4fpvkm4fq-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0/bin/cardano-cli"
error: getting status of /nix/var/nix/daemon-socket/socket: Operation not permitted
rewrite-libs: ProcFailed {procCommand = "nix-store", procArguments = ["-r","/nix/store/vv3k4s0gzkvdbirq5iiah15w920z6aql-zlib-1.2.11/lib/libz.dylib"], procExitCode = ExitFailure 1}
error: builder for '/nix/store/9r5f5sz773fnzc6vxch5l13jh9104mwg-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0.drv' failed with exit code 1;
       last 10 log lines:
       > Linking dist/build/cardano-cli/cardano-cli ...
       > installing
       > Installing executable cardano-cli in /nix/store/4hwiz5g25mnrjb3a6qjdcvl4fpvkm4fq-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0/bin
       > Warning: The directory
       > /nix/store/4hwiz5g25mnrjb3a6qjdcvl4fpvkm4fq-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0/bin
       > is not in the system search path.
       > Setting gitrev of /nix/store/4hwiz5g25mnrjb3a6qjdcvl4fpvkm4fq-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0/bin/cardano-cli ... OK
       > "Bundling /nix/store/vv3k4s0gzkvdbirq5iiah15w920z6aql-zlib-1.2.11/lib/libz.dylib in /nix/store/4hwiz5g25mnrjb3a6qjdcvl4fpvkm4fq-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0/bin/cardano-cli"
       > error: getting status of /nix/var/nix/daemon-socket/socket: Operation not permitted
       > rewrite-libs: ProcFailed {procCommand = "nix-store", procArguments = ["-r","/nix/store/vv3k4s0gzkvdbirq5iiah15w920z6aql-zlib-1.2.11/lib/libz.dylib"], procExitCode = ExitFailure 1}
       For full logs, run 'nix log /nix/store/9r5f5sz773fnzc6vxch5l13jh9104mwg-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0.drv'.
error: build of '/nix/store/8a0gn6kmpakh4m1lpmid599hmcckbfrc-cardano-node-exe-cardano-node-1.33.0.drv', '/nix/store/9r5f5sz773fnzc6vxch5l13jh9104mwg-cardano-cli-exe-cardano-cli-1.33.0.drv', '/nix/store/anmrbbdiymirc2npqkcnmf3ih3f06jkn-updateMaterialized.drv', '/nix/store/b0q86i19kw66v5v8r21p1z8rs2mgm6dc-pre-commit-config.json.drv', '/nix/store/h4xywd2yqdgm4qf7ignnaw7llspwwvhs-plutus-playground-generate-purs.drv', '/nix/store/n8124sfkdbmjjjva72lh4yxp9m19r1wd-cardano-wallet-2021.12.15.drv', '/nix/store/spc349lqq5mx4j9fwzfpywqzbjxbqgj9-update-client-deps.drv', '/nix/store/wpz2b0xzw3fi84knb9ldnfp7q5175qhi-plutus-playground-server.drv', '/nix/store/z6xqdvz6grjpxdkkp3k2g47zyd2hw8hq-python3-3.9.6-env.drv' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution!!
Thanks to

[starting nix-shell on mac "Operation not permitted"](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/6317/starting-nix-shell-on-mac-operation-not-permitted)

MacOs seems to require that the Nix Sandbox setting is set to OFF. I have turned it on, while setting Nix, as I read somewhere that it should be turning  ON (It seems that by default it is OFF in MacOS, so if you didn't changed it in the nix.conf you should be ok)

I was able to have my nix-shell up and running now!

Comment: If the question is a duplicate, remove this question and answer.

Comment: Please take the tour and see the guidelines in the help cemter